# Overlay a white text on a white background image in android

Tags: android

I am building with android studio and I have a white background image with a white text, the white text is overlayed on the white background image. This is how my codes looks

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chanImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/whiteImage">



        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:text="WHITE TEXT"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please is there a way to make the white text visible whiles it is on the white background. I would be grateful to know.

Comment: It can't be visible if the colors are the same. Change one of the colors to another nuance. You could use a light gray color as the background

Comment: The background image has a dynamic container, which could contain different colours such as the gray, so even if i make the text colour gray and when the background also changes it creates the conflict

Comment: Can't you handle only the case when the background is white?

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori Please that is why I  posted it, if could handle the background with white image then i can handle any other colour.

Comment: post the code how you change the background then

Answer (score 4):

Add shadow to the text, something like

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:text="WHITE TEXT"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:shadowColor="#55000000"
            android:shadowDx="6"
            android:shadowDy="6"
            android:shadowRadius="6"
            />
```

You can also use the image as the TextView background and eliminate the ImageView and potentially the RelativeLayout too, depending on your case.